# EasyHook DrawTextW user32.dll Injection, Application crashing

Tags: easyhook

I'm using EasyHook too hook calls to DrawTextW, while testing with notepad, if I open Help -> About, It captures all the text that appears on the screen as expected. However, if I open File -> Open, Notepad crashes. I don't expect it to capture any text, but I can't understand why notepad is crashing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
using EasyHook;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using UI;

namespace MyClassLibrary
{
    public class Main : IEntryPoint
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct HDC__
        {
            public int unused;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct tagRECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "DrawTextW")]
        public static extern int DrawTextW([In()] IntPtr hdc, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder lpchText, int cchText, ref tagRECT lprc, uint format);


        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public delegate int TDrawTextW(
          [In()] IntPtr hdc,
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
          StringBuilder lpchText,
          int cchText,
          ref tagRECT lprc,
          uint format);


        static string ChannelName;
        RemoteMon Interface;

        LocalHook DrawTextWHook;
        public Main(RemoteHooking.IContext InContext, String InChannelName)
        {
            try
            {
                Interface = RemoteHooking.IpcConnectClient<RemoteMon>(InChannelName);
                ChannelName = InChannelName;
                Interface.IsInstalled(RemoteHooking.GetCurrentProcessId());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Interface.ErrorHandler(ex);
            }
        }

        static int hkDrawTextW(
                  [In()] IntPtr hdc,
                  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
                  StringBuilder lpchText,
                  int cchText,
                  ref tagRECT lprc,
                  uint format)
        {
            try
            {
                ((Main)HookRuntimeInfo.Callback).Interface.GotDrawTextW(lpchText);
                return DrawTextW(hdc, lpchText, cchText, ref lprc, format);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ((Main)HookRuntimeInfo.Callback).Interface.ErrorHandler(ex);
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public void Run(RemoteHooking.IContext InContext, String InChannelName)
        {
            try
            {
                DrawTextWHook = LocalHook.Create(LocalHook.GetProcAddress("user32.dll", "DrawTextW"),
                                                new TDrawTextW(hkDrawTextW), this);
                DrawTextWHook.ThreadACL.SetExclusiveACL(new Int32[] { 0 });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Interface.ErrorHandler(ex);
            }
            try
            {
                RemoteHooking.WakeUpProcess();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Interface.ErrorHandler(ex);
            }
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend attaching the debugger to notepad and see if that helps. Also try changing your hook function to do nothing other than return the original value.

Comment: I did try commenting out the GotDrawTextW call before and got the same results. I'll try to see if I can find out more info with the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with marshalling the text to a StringBuilder when the Open dialog shows. I'm not 100% sure of the reason, but perhaps the difference between a COM initialised string and one initialised with malloc? I have experienced marshalling issues with strings in the past depending on how their underlying memory has been initialised.

The solution is to use a String instead of a StringBuilder for the text parameter. Replace the extern and the delegate and other appropriate areas with a string parameter:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "DrawTextW")]
    public static extern int DrawTextW([In()] IntPtr hdc, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String lpchText, int cchText, ref tagRECT lprc, uint format);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public delegate int TDrawTextW(
      [In()] IntPtr hdc,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
      String lpchText,
      int cchText,
      ref tagRECT lprc,
      uint format);

    static int hkDrawTextW(
              [In()] IntPtr hdc,
              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
              String lpchText,
              int cchText,
              ref tagRECT lprc,
              uint format)
    {
      ...
    }
```

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem nicely. Hard to find information on this type of stuff.

Comment: Glad to help, yeah its tricky to help with these because it is generally hard to diagnose the issue from looking at code alone, often requires to reproduce it in code and that takes time and effort.